# Problem with an Expression in Attribute Assistant?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, attribute-assistant

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop in a versioned environment.  I am also using ESRI Attribute Assistant to autopopulate fields using a custom expression.

My Table Names, Field Names, Value Method, etc... all are working fine.  My problem is with my expression below:

```
iif(InStr(UCase([REQUEST_TYPE]), "SEW") > 0,  VbNull , "Inspection")
```

The problem here is the expression, if it finds "SEW" in the [REQUEST_TYPE] it is returning a `1` instead of a `<NULL>` , otherwise it is returning `"Inspection"` fine.

Why is it returning a 1 ?  Also how can I fix this.  I have tried `'Nothing'` , `Nothing` , and `<NULL>`  instead of `VbNull` but nothing seems to work.  What would the correct Expression be?

I tried some more things,  I currently have the EXPRESSION setup as:

```
iif(InStr(UCase([REQUEST_TYPE]), "SEW") > 0,  "" , "Inspection")
```

so that it returning a "" if "SEW" is found in [REQUEST_TYPE] , though this is better, I would still prefer a NULL value if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Null` instead of `VbNull`:

```
iif(InStr(UCase([REQUEST_TYPE]), "SEW") > 0,  Null , "Inspection")
```

Although this also seems to enter an empty value rather than a true `NULL`, which is odd.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: I get similar results with Null rather than VbNull.  I'm still researching this myself.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The magic word here is `"<Null>"`:

```
iif(InStr(UCase([REQUEST_TYPE]), "SEW") > 0,  "<Null>" , "Inspection")
```

Tested on 10.2. This seems to actually nullify it instead of putting an empty string or other unexpected value.

Note that if a field doesn't allow null values this will still fail, e.g.:

```
ERROR: evaluating the expression for feature in [featureclass] with OID of 948799
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040659): The field is not nullable.
```